# Fedora 29 won't finish booting

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

When my Fedora 29 system boots, after I enter the disk password, it gets stuck on the black loading screen with three orange squares. I have a live USB I can use to exam the system but I am not sure where to look for. Are there any common causes for this? I know this is a vague question, but it's perplexing as it was booting fine earlier today and AFAIK nothing changed at the system level.